# How to clear in notifications in notification center for android and ios applications using nativescript-angular?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

Hai iam developing android and ios application using native script-angular.I am using fcm notifications for my apps, I want to clear the notification in the notification center when I click a button. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use [nativescript-local-notifications](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications) and use `cancelAll()` method.

```
LocalNotifications.cancelAll();
```

Comment: the notifications were triggered by fcm. how to clear fcm notifications?

Comment: Irrespective of who triggers the notification, it's all within your app and the same APIs are used to construct notifications. So it should work.

Comment: LocalNotifications.cancelAll() method was not clearing the fcm notifications

Comment: I want to clear the delivered notifications in the notification panel

Comment: Thank you, Manoj for replying my question. I have found a solution to my question. I have fixed by accessing native API's

Answer (score 0):

```
// Best solution is as below for the devices >= Marshmello.

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        for (StatusBarNotification statusBarNotification : notificationManager.getActiveNotifications()) {
            //  if (KEY_MESSAGE_GROUP.equals(statusBarNotification.getGroupKey()))
            logApp(TAG, "deleteAllNotifications(), statusBarNotification.getId()- "+statusBarNotification.getId());
            notificationManager.cancel(statusBarNotification.getId());
        }
    }
```